# How to transcribe multiple audio files at once using Whisper finetuned model?

Tags: nlp, scripting, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, openai-whisper

**TL;DR: I'm trying to transcribe multiple files together using Hugging face fine-tuned whisper ai model and extract the output as a single text file**

I have this code which works and transcribes an audio and shows its output as a string of text. But I want to improve upon this by making this transcribe multiple files together, and exporting its output to a text file with each line representing a single audio file.

### What did I try?

Im not a coder but I asked bing to generate a code and it came up with this which has errors.

```
audio_files = ["/content/audio1", "/content/audio2", ..., "/content/audioN"]
transcriptions = []

for audio_file in audio_files:
    transcription = pipe(audio_file, chunk_length_s=10, stride_length_s=(4, 2))
    transcriptions.append(transcription)

with open("transcriptions.txt", "w") as f:
    for transcription in transcriptions:
        f.write(transcription + "\n")
```

### What I want?

I need a code which transcribes **all the audio that I have into a single text file** on which each line represents an audio file(preferably starting with the file name). If I **can specify a folder which has all the files** for transcription instead of entering each file manually, that would be AWESOME.

### Whats my workspace?

I'm using hugging face open ai whisper(fine-tuned) to transcribe my files on google colab.

Any of your help is deeply appreciated.